# Finding critical point between two roots

Tags: roots

For finding a critical point like A ($f′(x(A))=0$) between x=α and x=β in $f(x)=(x-α)^m(x-β)^n$ I use this formula:
$$x(A)=\frac{α.n+β.m}{m+n}$$
but I am interesting to know is there any formula like this to calculate the approximate or exact abscissa of a critical point between two roots of a function like $f(x)=(x-α)^m(x-β)^n\dots(x-γ)^t$ which has more than two roots?

Comment: What does $x(A)$ mean? I see that $f$ is a function and $x$ is the undetermined (variable)...Thanks.

Comment: x(A) means abscissa of critical point A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From

$$
f(x)=(x-α)^m(x-β)^n(x-γ)^t
$$

deriving we have

$$
f'(x)=m(x-α)^{m-1}(x-β)^n(x-γ)^t+n(x-α)^m(x-β)^{n-1}(x-γ)^t+t (x-α)^m(x-β)^n(x-γ)^{t-1}=0
$$

and

$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{m}{x-\alpha}+\frac{n}{x-\beta}+\frac{t}{x-\gamma}=0
$$

and now we have a second order polynomial... So for $k$ terms the polynomial to solve will be of order $k-1$